# I stuck in blur function in problem set 4 of cs50 (filter-more). don't know why the resulting pic is very weird

Tags: c, rgb, cs50, blur

Here's the [Problem Set 4 Filter-more](https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2023/psets/4/filter/more/).
Here's my code.

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE temp[height][width];
    // for the calculation of the averages of RGB values
    BYTE blue_sum, green_sum, red_sum;
    float counter;
    // inclusive lower and upper bounds
    int lower_bound_row, upper_bound_row, lower_bound_col, upper_bound_col;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        lower_bound_row = (i - 1 < 0)? i : i - 1;
        upper_bound_row = (i + 1 == height)? i : i + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            blue_sum = 0; green_sum = 0; red_sum = 0;
            counter = 0.00;
            lower_bound_col = (j - 1 < 0)? j : j - 1;
            upper_bound_col = (j + 1 == width)? j : j + 1;

            // Adding the color values of neighboring pixels
            for (int a = lower_bound_row; a <= upper_bound_row; a++)
            {
                for (int b = lower_bound_col; b <= upper_bound_col; b++)
                {
                    blue_sum += image[a][b].rgbtBlue;
                    green_sum += image[a][b].rgbtGreen;
                    red_sum += image[a][b].rgbtRed;
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            // Dividing the sums by no. of neighing pixels to calculate the averages
            temp[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue_sum / counter);
            temp[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green_sum / counter);
            temp[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red_sum / counter);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            image[i][j] = temp[i][j];
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

I tried to use debug50 but I couldn't track the rgb values of each pixel so I couldn't figure out what's wrong. Thank you to anyone who trys to help! Thank you!

Comment: What does check50 say? Describe weird or add a before and after image to the question. A `BYTE` is not large enough to hold the sum of 9 pixels. Use an `int`.

Comment: Ohh you're right! It's becuase uint8_t only stores values from 0 to 255! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Retired Ninja for helping me out!! Finally just **change the blue_sum, green_sum and red_sum data type to int** and all good :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).